# Definitions of vector field on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and of vector field on a smooth manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-fields

There is something I don't understand in the definition(s) of a vector field.

A **vector field on $\mathbb{R}^n$** is a continuous map $X: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$.

Considering an arbitrary smooth $n$-manifold $M$.
A *vector field on M* is a continuous section of the tangent bundle $TM$, i.e. a continuous map $X: M \to TM$ such that $p \circ X = \mathrm{id}_M$ (where $p: TM \to M$ is the bundle projection).

Now, here is my question.
Consider an arbitrary continuous map $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$, by definition, $X \circ f$ is again a **vector field on $\mathbb{R}^n$**, right ?
However, consider now that $M = \mathbb{R}^n$.
If we consider again the map $f$, by definition, I cannot see why $X \circ f$ is now a *vector field on $M$* (due to the fact that $p \circ (X \circ f) = \mathrm{id}_M$ is not true in general).

So, I see two options:

1- The notion of "vector field on a smooth manifold" does not aim to generalize the notion of "vector field on $\mathbb{R}^n$", and I find it really strange.
As differential geometry generalizes what we can do in Euclidean spaces, it seems weird to accept that those definitions of "vector field" are just different. I would find it more natural to define a notion of "vector field on a smooth manifold" which stick directly to the definition of "vector field on $\mathbb{R}^n$", as a particular case.

2- We can "fix the problem" and I do not see clearly how.
More generally, if we suppose that $TM$ is trivial (i.e. if $TM$ is isomorphic, as a vector bundle, to $M \times \mathbb{R}^n$), why could we say that a vector field on $M$ is a map from $M$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$ ? I mean, even if, after identification, any vector field $X$ on $M$ is such that $X(m) = (m,v)$, for some $v \in \mathbb{R}^n$, there is still a problem, no ?

Thanks for your help !

Comment: The reason why $X \circ f$ is a vector field on $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ is because all tangent spaces of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ can be canonically identified with $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. Now suppose $M$ is a regular surface of $\mathbb{R}^{3}$. Are all tangent spaces of $M$ canonically isomorphic?

Comment: If $M$ is a submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^3$, for every $x,y \in M$, $T_xM$ and $T_yM$ are isomorphic, no ? I think that I don't really understand what you mean by "canonically".

Comment: The word "canonically" means that you can define an explicit isomorphism without the need of coordinates. A canonical isomorphism between, say, $T_{x}M$ and $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ must not depend on a coordinate system around $x$, since there is more than one way to define coordinates around $x$.

Comment: For example, if $M=\mathbb{R}^{n}$, for every $p\in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ the map $v\in \mathbb{R}^{n}\mapsto \frac{d}{dt}\big|_{t=0}p+tv$ is an isomorphism between $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ and $T_{p}(M)$, the space of all derivations at $p$.

Comment: Ah, I understand ! Thanks for your explanations !

Answer (score 2):

Maps $M\to \mathbb R^n$ are in bijection with sections $M\to M\times \mathbb R^n$ over $M$, this is how the two  notions are translated into each other. Explicitly, the bijection is obtained by sending a map $X\colon M\to \mathbb R^n$ to $(\operatorname{id}, X)$, and it's converse is given by postcomposing a section with the with the projection onto $M$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So, in the case where $TM$ is trivial, it means that I have "no risk" to consider vector fields as maps from $M$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$ ? I mean, does the fact that theses two sets are in bijection is enough ? Do we need more than that (like "homeomorphic", for some topological structures on these sets) ?

Comment: Yes that's usually enough.

Comment: Many thanks ! ;)

Comment: @deeppinkwater In fact, when $M$ is parallelisable (that is $TM$ is trivialisable), the trivialisation is a diffeomorphism, not only a bijection.

Comment: @Didier I'm not sure to understand... The trivialisation $\phi: TM  \to M \times \mathbb{R}^n$ is a diffeomorphism, but what is exactly the link with the bijection $\{\text{maps from } M \text{ to } \mathbb{R}^n\} \to \{\text{sections of } M\}$ ?

Comment: @deeppinkwater Well, maybe "diffeomorphism" was a too strong word here. I should have said "linear isomorphisms". The space of sections of a vector bundle, as well as the space of functions $M \to \mathbb{R}^n$, are vector spaces, and one can (under some hypothesis on $M$, let's say compactness for the sake of simplicity) endow these spaces with some topological structures, *etc.* so that this is "more than a bijection".

Comment: @Didier Sorry, I just saw your answer. Yes, I understand, but my question is rather "do we need these extra structures" ? For example, I am interested in proving that two vector fields on a parallelisable manifold $M$ are homotopic (with a homotopy maintaining some properties). The thing is that it is way more easy for me in that case to consider that these vector fields are maps from $M$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$ (without entering into details: I need to compose them with some homeomorphism). The problem is that I am not sur that, simply because these two sets are in bijection, I am allowed to do so.